# Is there a way to use a 'pass by reference' in a class constructor?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I have a class which contains multiple public functions which all interact with the same `$_SESSION` index/variable. Rather than passing that variable into each function every time they are called I would like to simply pass it into the class constructor and have the functions grab it from `$this->`.

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = array('foo', 'bar');

class MyClass {
    // Pass by reference in ___construct arguments
    public function __construct(&$test_var) {
        $this->test_var = $test_var;
    }
    public function unset_foo() {
        unset($this->test_var[0]);
    }
}

$bar = new MyClass($_SESSION['test']);
$bar->unset_foo();

print_r($_SESSION['test']);
```

The result should then be:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 'bar'
)
```

This does not work though.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always have to pass by ref:

In this line you are not assigning by reference, but copying the value:

```
    $this->test_var = $test_var;
```

Just add an `&` there, so that `$this->test_var` still holds a reference to `$_SESSION['test']`:

```
    $this->test_var = &$test_var;
```

Comment: Perfect, that did it. Thanks for the help. Will set this as answer when it lets me.